# Firebase for Unity using service accounts hangs fetching auth token

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, service-accounts

I installed the shiny new Firebase for Unity package and am trying to get the database package to work using a service account, as detailed here. I was able to connect to and work with the database (without a service account) when the rules are left public, but not when using a service account.

Enabling verbose logging ( `FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose;` ) gives me:

```
PersistentConnection:pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
ConnectionRetryHelper:Scheduling retry in %dms
PersistentConnection:pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
```

Then after a a min or two:

```
PersistentConnection:pc_0 - Connection interrupted for: connection_idle
```

I've tried giving the service account the Owner role and making it DwD. Neither helps.

Has anyone been able to get this working? Do I need to do something special when setting up the service account? Do I need to do something in Firebase after setting up the service account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a response from Firebase after submitting a request for help. They will be including a fix for this problem in their next release.

Answer (score 0):

(This is John Butterfield from the Firebase C++ / Unity team.)

The fix for this is released in Firebase 4.3.0 https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#4.3.0.